# Is the following example of one parameter group correct?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In [this book (An Introduction to Lie Groups and the Geometry of Homogeneous Spaces)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z4vxBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA15&ots=wUmKbodbDM&dq=one-parameter%20subgroup%20of%20the%20additive%20Lie%20group%20R.&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false) the author gives the following example of one parameter group:

> The map $\varphi(t) = e^t$ is a one-parameter subgroup of the **additive**
>   Lie group $\Bbb R$.

Is this correct? because 
$$\varphi(t+s)=e^{t+s}=e^t.e^s\neq \varphi(t)+\varphi(s).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake. The map $\varphi(t) = e^t$ is a one-parameter subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^+$; and the map $\varphi(t)=t$ is a one-parameter subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Prof. Jack Lee many many many thanks.